# Hazelcast ReplicatedMap serialization into file

Tags: java, serialization, filesystems, hazelcast

I am trying to save ReplicatedMap (hazelcast) to filesystem and load it later, but it seems not possible. Is there any way how to achieve this?

details:

```
Map map = HazelcastInstance.getReplicatedMap("map");
File file = new File("hazelcastmap");
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
s.writeObject(map);
s.close();
```

the error thrown is:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.hazelcast.replicatedmap.impl.ReplicatedMapProxy
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
```

Is there any way how to read and write ReplicatedMap into file.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ReplicatedMap is a structure intended to keep references for objects, you have to write your own code to serialize the ReplicatedMap's information into a file. Below is a crude example to do this in a (very) old fashioned way

```
private static void writeToFile(){

    // Retrieve your hazelcast reference
    // hazelcast = ...

    Map<Object, Object> map = hazelcast.getReplicatedMap("map");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/out.data");

    ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(arrayOut);

    dataOut.writeInt(map.size());

    for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){

        dataOut.writeUTF(entry.getKey().toString());
        dataOut.writeUTF(entry.getValue().toString());
    }

    fos.write(arrayOut.toByteArray());

    //..close streams
}

private static void readFromFile() throws Exception{

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/tmp/out.data");
    DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(fis);

    Map<Object, Object> map = hazelcast.getReplicatedMap("map");

    int size = dataIn.readInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        String key = dataIn.readUTF();
        String value = dataIn.readUTF();

        //Convert the String 'value' into your Object
        //put the pair key value into the map
    }

    //..close streams
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So best way for serializing will be to take the values from ReplicatedMap, put them into say HashMap, and serialize/deserialize this. Then use ReplicatedMap:putAll(HashMap) to load the values for ReplicatedMap.